# Castle Windsor - How can a low-level Container install from top-level Installers?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have several different WCF service host processes. Each of these is dependent on a single, lower level, business logic DLL.

The DLL currently makes use of a home-grown dependency injection mechanism that's based on XML files. There is a lot of variance in the component implementations between the top-level processes.

I would like to replace this DI mechanism with a proper DI tool: [Castle Windsor](https://www.castleproject.org/projects/windsor/). I would also like to shift from XML based configuration to explicit configuration in code via [`WindsorInstaller`](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/installers.md)s.

One last constraint is that it is not feasible (at this time) to lift the DI container from the low-level DLL to the top-level processes.

So my question is - Given that a `WindsorContainer` will reside in the low-level DLL, how can it discover implementations of `IWindsorInstaller` provided by a top-level process that will run it?

I would prefer a solution based on Windsor's API but I've not been able to make  successful use of its [`FromAssembly`](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/installers.md#fromassembly-class) feature.

Answer (score 1):

The by far preferred option would be to lift it to the host process, but if it's not feasible at this time, as you said, I'd probably recommend the `FromAssembly` approach.

Alternatively, although I'd normally not recommend it, it might be worthwhile to look at [XML configuration for installers](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-installers.md).